# Complex data structures while embedding\extending Python with C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, extending, python-embedding

Python documentation gives a nice introduction to [Extending and Embedding Python with C\C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html). However, in many cases there's a need to transfer complex data structures between the languages.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create your own type](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#defining-new-types) and fill the `tp_*attr` members appropriately.

Comment: Do I really need to create a new type just to transfer a struct from C\C++ to Python and back? Isn't there a way to map it to a dictionary for instance?

Comment: Also - If I do create a new type - would I need to convert the data between it and the C\C++ data structure in C\C++?

Comment: You don't actually "transfer" anything between C/C++ and Python; a type instance holds the struct as a member, and the `tp_*attr` functions convert data back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC Boost.Python http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you here.